# Did Selina Kyle know the secret identity of Bruce Wayne before she gave him to Bane?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

Did Selina know the secret identity of Bruce?

Because when she saw that Batman was back on the news she was like: "well what do you know?"

Comment: The second part of your question is answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/how-did-john-blake-make-his-discovery?rq=1), so I've removed it. The first part stands alone as a decent question

Answer (score 8):

### No, she didn't

The novelization confirms that she had no idea until it was too late (emphasis mine):

> "Bane."
>
> The infamous mercenary approached him.
>
> "Let's not stand on ceremony here, Mr. Wayne."
>
> Batman wasn't surprised that Bane knew his true identity. The man was connected to the League of Shadows, after all - he likely had heard of Bruce Wayne’s tangled history with Rā's al Ghūl.
>
> **Catwoman, on the other hand, was visibly taken aback by the revelation. A look of regret came over her face, as though she was having second thoughts about betraying him.**
>
> <sup>*The Dark Knight Rises: The Official Novelization* Chapter 20</sup>

Comment: Hathaway does a pretty good look of regret in the movie too.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite [I agree](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/134897/3) ;) But it's harder to talk about facial expressions (especially since it was apparently non-obvious to the OP), so I axed it in favour of the direct quote